# Hook for redirection on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404

I am making a custom theme on wordpress. And rather than installing a plugin, I would like to know how to do a `404` redirect with a hook in the `functions.php` file.

So if the user goes to "my-domain.com/page/sub-page" how do I get a `404` page on this url?

I created a `404.php` page in my custom theme.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have the answer:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page/sub-page/') !== false ) 
    {
        wp_redirect('/404/');
        exit;
    }
});
```

Another solution:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page/sub-page/') !== false ) {
        status_header(404);
        get_template_part(404);
        exit();
    }
});
```